# Capture SQL Server connections

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to capture SQL Server connections for when a user connects to my database until the user disconnects. For example, I want to capture login data for every user that accesses my SQL Server through Excel. Is there a trigger or DMV that will capture the time the user spent connected? I've used sysprocesses in the past and it will show me the connections and from what program, but I need it to be more like a trigger.

Comment: maybe put `sp_who2` in a trigger?  And who says you cant put sysprocess into a trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [auditing functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175850.aspx) built into sql server.

Maybe you can use this to accomplish your goals (you can capture success and fail login attempts)

ADDED INFO

This webpage above is specifically re: login auditing - introduced in sql 2005

ADDED INFO PART DEUX

Read your question again, and see you want the duration not (not just the login) -- a little harder, but, see the [reference for sp_trace_setevent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx). You should see events for login and logoff here. I've heard that capture logout is a bit more server intensive. Also, not that people do not always ***logout***. They lose connections, crash the machine, etc. not sure how trustworthy the logout data will be. Connection pooling may also complicate you life.